# Extract from column only the digits and split to different columns

Tags: python, pandas, string, split, digits

I have very big dataframe that a row in it typically looks like that:

```
>>>ID    name    year    location
0  341   Dali    1995   {{"{\"latitude\":\"9.4714611480000004\",\"longitude\":\"4.3520187860000004\"}","{\"latitude\":\"9.4720611479999999\",\"longitude\":\"4.3520187860000004\"}}
...
```

df['geolocation'] = df['geolocation'].str.replace(r'\D', '')
I would like to break the location column into many columns that contain only the numebrs and to get rid of the "latitude", "longtitude" and all the symbols in between.

I thouhgt to do it first by extract only the digits like this:

```
df['location'] = df['location'].str.extract('(\d+)', expand=False)
```

but that for some reason gave me the location column as ine integer number.

I didn't want to use split because the symbols in the middle are not consistent, somtimes you have this sequence : {{"{" and sometimes it can be only "{"{"  and I can't really trace all the possibilites that might be there. also the number of digits  is different in the different rows.

**My desired result should look like this:**

```
>>>ID    name    year    lat                 long                     lat1          long1 ....
0  341   Dali    1995    9.4714611480000004  4.3520187860000004 9.4720611479999999 4.3520187860000004
```

edit: I have also tried this:

```
df['location'] = df['location'].str.replace(r'\D', '')
```

which preserved the numbers but gave me one very ling number ,without preservring the "." and also without haveing any space between the numbers

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have used regex match for efficient extraction of latitudes and longitudes. This can obtained using following code.

```
import re
import pandas as pd

df = pd.DataFrame({
    'ID': [341,321],
    'name':['Dali','daLi'],
    'year':[1995, 1996],
    'location':['{{"{\"latitude\":\"9.4714611480000004\",\"longitude\":\"4.3520187860000004\"}","{\"latitude\":\"9.4720611479999999\",\"longitude\":\"4.3520187860000004\"}}',
                '{{"{\"latitude\":\"9.4714611480000004\",\"longitude\":\"4.3520187860000004\"}","{\"latitude\":\"9.4720611479999999\",\"longitude\":\"4.3520187860000004\"}}']
})
```

Solution

```
df_new = df.location.apply(lambda x: re.findall(r"\d+\.*\d*",x))
df_new = pd.DataFrame(df_new.to_list(), columns=['lat1','long1','lat2','long2'])
pd.concat([df.iloc[:,0:3], df_new], axis=1)
```

output

```
    ID  name    year    lat1                long1               lat2                long2
0   341 Dali    1995    9.4714611480000004  4.3520187860000004  9.4720611479999999  4.3520187860000004
1   321 daLi    1996    9.4714611480000004  4.3520187860000004  9.4720611479999999  4.3520187860000004
```

Comment: @Rangar thank you for youranswer, could you either elaborate what does the /d  ot d+ means, or just  tell me where can I read about this way of writing? iI don't understand the logic of this and would like to understand more :)

Comment: \d+ selects digits (1 or more) , \.* selects . (zero or more), \d*  selects digits (zero or more)

Comment: @Ranger is therename for this so  I can read about that?